# Bought Bitcoin from ATM, haven't showed up

Tags: wallet, buy-bitcoins, payment, spv

I made two transactions at a BTC ATM, one of around £80, the other of £10. It has now been >3 hours since the transaction was made. However, only the smaller transaction has appeared in my Bitcoin wallet. Blockchain.info shows no unconfirmed payments. So, can anyone advise me on what is going on?

Cheers.

EDIT 1: No changes after half an hour, on TradeBlock, my address has no pending transactions listed, is this significant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of wallet are you using?  I ask because if you're using a full node (like bitcoin core) then it could be that you need to wait for the latest blocks to finish uploading...or... it could be that the transaction for £80 hasn't had a confirmation yet and we're still waiting for that confirmation before it appears in your mobile wallet.

[image: Screenshot of the latest blocks solved]

Using tradeblock (the screenshot) we can see that there's about 1,718 tx still waiting to be confirmed in the queue and that the last block happened 6 minutes ago...I'm guessing that it wasn't in that full Bitfury Block there so it's likely still waiting to be confirmed.

Final edit:  Electrum is an spv wallet, likely you're waiting for a confirmation as it should download the block headers pretty much instantly.

Do this...close Electrum...then reopen it..I don't expect your balance to update but maybe it will (if there's some sort of bug or network timeout issue happening)...from there...give it about another 30 or so mins for it to be included in the next block...this happens because sometimes bitcoin ATMs send non-standard trx and the fee is low (compared to free market).  I believe the recommended fee is approximately 10 satoshis per byte and we see the average fee is about 14 in the pic above.  Taking my comments into consideration - don't worry about the coin being lost it should still hit your address balance.  The worst case scenario is this:  in 72 hours if the coin fails to route then the ATMs wallet gets the coin back - you would be able to reference the failed transaction with the atm operator to get your money back or request them to send the coin with a higher fee so it confirms faster.

Comment: I am using Electrum (2.5.4)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the Screenshot, what's your estimation for confirmation?

Comment: I'll do as you suggested. I'll update if anything comes of it. Cheers man!

Comment: Hi, I'm on the TradeBlock website looking at the live blocks. What should i be looking at for indication of progress in mining the next block?

Comment: Also, there are no 'pending' transactions when i look up my address on TradeBlock.

Comment: @Liton12 its always in progress (I suppose you could guess that if its been more than 10 minutes then a block should generate fairly soon statistically speaking), but its always random sometimes they appear one after another like rapid-fire. If there is no pending transactions on your address that could be a problem, because it should show instantly as unconfirmed...check with the atm operator right away in this case.

Comment: I'll get on their case now, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Coin is in my wallet - The provider sorted it out. Thanks for the help!